# Issue sending CloudWatch Event to SNS (Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-connect

I want to have CloudTrail send a Connect API call to CloudWatch (it works) then have an event push an SNS to my email.
I have this working with Alarms but I want a custom message which I can't do in Alarms.

I believe it to be the way I have configured the Event Pattern for the rule.
The Event details in the CloudTrail API call is
"eventSource": "connect.amazonaws.com",
"eventName": "DeleteUser"

and I have attached an image of the configured Event Pattern.
Cheers!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqNNO.jpg